# How to add Line to tr with nested *ngFor and last line should not print

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to print invoice in the web there are some services which are printing in invoice and I am separating those services using line

```
let invoiceData=[ 
            {
                "categoryName" : "Bleach",
                "services" : [ 
                    {
                        "price" : 250,
                        "quantitySelected" : 1,
                        "serviceName" : "Face",
                        "discount" : 25,
                        "employee" : { 
                            "employeeName":"Arun kavale",
                            "employeeId":"5ba9e42bb43046563a1b0bbf"
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "price" : 300,
                        "quantitySelected" : 1,
                        "serviceName" : "Full Hands excluding Under Arms",
                        "employee" : { 
                            "employeeName":"Arun kavale",
                            "employeeId":"5ba9e42bb43046563a1b0bbf"
                        }
                    }
                ]

            },
            {
                "categoryName" : "Bleach 2",
                "services" : [ 
                    {
                        "price" : 250,
                        "quantitySelected" : 1,
                        "serviceName" : "Face 2",
                        "employee" : { 
                            "employeeName":"Arun kavale",
                            "employeeId":"5ba9e42bb43046563a1b0bbf"
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "price" : 300,
                        "quantitySelected" : 1,
                        "serviceName" : "Full Hands excluding Under Arms 2",
                        "employee" : { 
                            "employeeName":"Arun kavale",
                            "employeeId":"5ba9e42bb43046563a1b0bbf"
                        }
                    }
                ]

            }
        ]
```

> please Have a look on this ... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l9darz?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
<div 
  style="vertical-align: top;border: black 1px solid;width: 100%;-webkit-border-radius: 19px; -moz-border-radius: 19px;border-radius: 19px;margin-right: 5%">
  <div 
    style="width: 100%;margin-left: 2%;margin-right: 2%;margin-top: 3%;margin-bottom: 3%">
    <table 
      *ngFor="let item of invoiceData; let i = index; let k = index; let last1 = last" 
      class="invoice-items;border-collapse: collapse;" 
      style="width:95%" 
      cellpadding="0" 
      cellspacing="0">
      <tr 
        *ngFor="let ser of item.services; let k = index; let first = first; let last = last" 
        style="border: solid;border-width: 1px 0;">

        <td 
          *ngIf="!last||first" 
          style="width: 50%;font-size: 120%;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(95, 94, 94);">
          {{ser.serviceName}}
        </td>

        <td 
          *ngIf="!last||first " 
          style="width: 25%;font-size: 120%;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(95, 94, 94);">
          EMP -{{ser.employee?.employeeName}} 
        </td>

        <td 
          *ngIf="!last||first" 
          style="width: 25%;font-size: 120%;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;text-align:right;border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(95, 94, 94);">
          {{ser.price}}.0 INR 
        </td>

        <td 
          *ngIf="last" 
          style="width: 50%;font-size: 120%;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;">
          {{ser.serviceName}}
        </td>

        <td 
          *ngIf="last" 
          style="width: 25%;font-size: 120%;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;">
          EMP -{{ser.employee?.employeeName}} 
        </td>

        <td 
          *ngIf="last" 
          style="width: 25%;font-size: 120%;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;text-align:right;">
          {{ser.price}}.0 INR 
        </td>

      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the code I wrote but. it's not printing line in between because last is coming multiple times so ... please help me to come out from this.. and here if i select only one service it is printing two times.

Comment: Please add some data to test this against.

Comment: I have added data